# Installing libwww-perl on Ubuntu 12.04,SE

Tags: 12.04, ssh, perl

I have an Ubuntu 12.04 server edition which I ssh into.

I am running Perl scripts on this server but it fails when I load

```
'use LWP::UserAgent;' with error message:
Can't locate LWP/UserAgent.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/hermann/scripts/modules/ /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at 1_standalone line 5.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at 1_standalone line 5.
```

So in order to fix that I am trying to install LWP::UserAgent, which I am told is by:
sudo apt-get install libwww-perl

But when I run that command i get the following error:

```
Failed to fetch http://is.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libf/libfont-afm-perl/libfont-afm-perl_1.20-1_all.deb  Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://is.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libh/libhtml-tagset-perl/libhtml-tagset-perl_3.20-2_all.deb  Size mismatch
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Now I have tried doing sudo apt-get update, which appears to run fine but doesn't change anything.
And I have also done 'sudo apt-get install libwww-perl --fix-missing', which also fails.

How do I install libwww-perl?

Answer (score 7):

First, I would strongly advise against the direct 'perl way' installs, they will only make the mess bigger. You don't need these in Ubuntu.  libwww-perl exists as a standard Ubuntu package.

Since this doesn't work.  You should start by cleaning up your installation which seems to be broken.  First, try cleaning-up your package installs like this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

and only when you don't get errors, move on to installing libwwww-perl, using:

```
sudo apt-get install libwww-perl
```

Also:

You seem to have a very unusual (non-standard) list of directories perl is searching libraries in.  For example, there shouldn't be a /etc/perl in the places to look for libraries, and on Ubuntu you don't need anything starting with /usr/local.

To check whether the package is installed, you may check the output of:

```
dpkg-query -S libwww-perl
```

Check your env for bad forced perl paths:

```
env | grep PERL
```

If this gives any output, I would remove it from the environment before running perl:
Look at your startup files (~/.bashrc in particular end comment these non standard settings out)

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the download server.
**Software sources -> Ubuntu Software -> Download from:** select the nearest geo from the list.

or

Try the Perl way of installion

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::LWP'
```

or

```
wget http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.04.tar.gz
tar xzf libwww-perl-6.04.tar.gz
cd libwww-perl-6.04
perl Makefile.PL
make
sudo make install
```

(My download source picked one of the India server to download the file http://perlmirror.indialinks.com/authors/id/G/GA/GAAS/libwww-perl-6.04.tar.gz )

If you are downloading the LWP module in your home directory then don't forget to add the path to your perl `@INC`

Comment: As this server is located at a distance from where I am, I am justing ssh-ing into it and therefore can't enter the gui. Which eliminates the first possibility. As for the latter, the Perl way, I tried it but received error: 'could not make: Unknown error'.

Comment: somehow messed up ubuntu's pkg list, fsck did not help, reinstalling all packages resulted in LWP::User Agent not found (albeit libwww-perl being installed). This worked! thanks