# Can't locate LWP

Tags: 14.04, perl, desktop-apps

After recent upgrade I can't launch only one of my apps it always gives me this error:

```
Can't locate LWP/UserAgent/Cached.pm in @INC (you may need to install the 
LWP::UserAgent::Cached module) (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local
/lib/perl/5.18.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.18.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share
/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.18 /usr/share/perl/5.18 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) 
at /usr/share/perl/5.18/WWW/YoutubeViewer.pm line 242.
```

I followed as in instructed in the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/180581/installing-libwww-perl-on-ubuntu-12-04-se) but all of those commands return positive outputs I got `libwww-perl` installed and running `apt-get dist-upgrade` doesn't give anything to upgrade either.

What else could I be missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

you'll need to install libwww-perl.

```
wget http://www.cpan.org/modules/by-module/LWP/libwww-perl-6.06.tar.gz
tar xvzf libwww-perl-6.06.tar.gz
cd libwww-perl-6.06
perl Makefile.PL
make
make install
```

or

```
apt-get install libwww-perl
```

Or you can try this solution

```
perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::LWP'
```

Comment: I installed it with `perl -MCPAN -e 'install Bundle::LWP'` but it still gives the same error :(

Comment: I have LWP inside perl5 folder in my Home Directory should I move it or change a path?

Comment: sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install LWP::UserAgent::Cached'

Comment: try the above command

Comment: it worked! thanks a lot! do I need to keep perl5 folder in my Home Dir?

Comment: You are welcome? no its not obligatory to keep it in your home

Comment: hmm just one more now it wants `you may need to install the JSON module` with the same error message I guess I need more modules how would I install JSON module?

Comment: try this `apt-get install libjson-perl`

Comment: I appreciate your help it worked again! now it doesn't ask for any more modules. Thanks again.

Comment: Brilliant @Maythux ...Perfect Solution libjson-perl! Running this in Termux and it fixed it for Me!

Answer (score 4):

Try to install the missing module from CPAN:

```
sudo perl -MCPAN -e 'install LWP::UserAgent::Cached'
```